# loading mnist data in keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

The below program must import mnist data from keras but the imported data consist only zeros. I have tried it on remote servers and again it has the same issue. Anyone knows why?

```
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.datasets import mnist

import numpy as np

from tempfile import TemporaryFile


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

data= np.concatenate((x_train, x_test), axis= 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mnist data consists of grayscale images of the 10 digits. Black background is representing by zeros and white number by integer numbers from 1 to 255 (255 means white).

You probable printed x_train and show only zeros in printed portion of the array, but this is not the case for whole array.
Try:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.mean(x_train))
```